# How can I create code that returns day of the week in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create a script that returns the day of the week,`s` is a string that represents the day of the week, and
`k` is an int that returns the day of the week that is K days later.

This is my code:

```
weekday = {
    "Mon": 0,
    "Tue": 1,
    "Wed": 2,
    "Thu": 3,
    "Fri": 4,
    "Sat": 5,
    "Sun": 6
}


def wd(s, k):
    s = list(weekday.values())[list(weekday.keys()).index(s)]
    k %= 7
    result = s + k
    return result


print(wd('Sat', 23))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
weekday = {
    "Mon": 0,
    "Tue": 1,
    "Wed": 2,
    "Thu": 3,
    "Fri": 4,
    "Sat": 5,
    "Sun": 6
}


def wd(s, k):
    s = list(weekday.values())[list(weekday.keys()).index(s)]
    k %= 7
    result = (s + k) % 7
    return result


for key, value in weekday.items():
    if value == wd('Sat', 1):
        print(key)
```

Comment: thanks! Now how to represent it as a string? In this case, s = 'Sat', k=23, output: 'Mon'

Comment: `for key, value in weekday.items():
    if value == wd('Sat', 1):
        print(key)`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `calendar` module:

```
import calendar
def wd(s, k):
    return (dict(zip(list(calendar.day_abbr), range(7)))[s] + k % 7) % 7

print(wd('Sat', 23))
```

Output:

```
0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function:

```
lst = list(weekday.keys())

def wd(s, k):
    return lst[weekday[s] + k % 7]

print(wd('Mon', 1))
# Tue
```